# Pytesseract OCR for single character on images

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I am trying to read text from the image , the image consist of single character it is not reading correctly. this is the type of images i have

[image]

it is reading this image as **'t'**

most of them it is reading incorrectly .

these are some of my images

[image]
[image]

this is my code

```
import pytesseract 
from PIL import Image 
import requests 
import io

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('15.png'), lang='eng',config='--psm 10')
print(text)
```